# Заполнить квадратную матрицу - пирамида, вид сверху

Tags: c++

Помогите с решением задачи.
Дано квадратная матрица, заполнить ее следующим образом:

```
1 1 1 1 1 
1 2 2 2 1 
1 2 3 2 1 
1 2 2 2 1 
1 1 1 1 1
```

Прошу подсказать мне, написать алгоритм ! 
Спасибо !

Comment: Подсказываю: значение в ячейке зависит от размера матрицы и расстояния от центра (как минимума из смещений по x и по y)

Comment: Цикл for вероятно ? Два раза, по оси х и по оси у.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажется, так:

```
a[i][j] = min(i+1, j+1, n-i, n-j);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var N = 7;

var m = [];
for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  m.push([]);
  for (var j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    m[i].push(0);
  }
}

// Метод "послойной укладки" :)
var start = 0, end = N - 1;
while (start <= end) {
  fillLayer(m, start++, end--);
}

function fillLayer(m, s, e) {
  for (var i = s; i <= e; i++) {
    for (var j = s; j <= e; j++) {
      m[i][j]++;
    }
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(m[i]));
}
```

Comment: Извините, разве это c++?

Comment: @BorisMakhlin Вы смотрели мультфильм "Заколдованный мальчик"?

Comment: Нет, не смотрел. Как это касается моей темы?

Comment: @BorisMakhlin Там гном сделал за Нильса задачу не его почерком. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CU5PsW3f9So

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < matrix.rows(); ++i) {
    for (std::size_t j = 0; j < matrix.cols(); ++j) {
        auto delta_i = std::min(i, matrix.rows() - i - 1);
        auto delta_j = std::min(j, matrix.cols() - j - 1);
        matrix(i, j) = std::min(delta_i, delta_j) + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: За что минус? Всё вроде правильно

Comment: В отличие от других вариантов на данный момент, кстати.

Comment: Из торжественного обещания участника ruSO: *"Клянусь ... без жалоб получать анонимные минусы, ..."*